# How to select GIF from gallery and show it in image-view

Tags: android, gif

How to select both normal and gif images from the gallery, and how to set condition whether the image selected is a gif or an image?

Below is the code where the image is selected from the gallery and is set in the `PhotoView` which is inside `FrameLayout`.The code `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap()` is used to select images from the gallery but how to select gif from the gallery and how to set check condition after the image is selected that whether that selected image is a gif or simple image

```
    PhotoView iv_add_player;
    String playerimagesave;
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Glide.with(this).load(uri).into(iv_add_player);
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
    bm=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
    //How to set Gif in above line??                  
      } 
    catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
      }
    playerimagesave = getImage(bm);
    iv_add_player.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

The above code is for the selection of gallery images but how to set gif images from gallery?

This onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){} function has the above code and is used here below-

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Comment: @user1241241 there is no bug my code is working. I need to set gif

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest [Glide Library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to show the gif, below is the code for reference:

```
GlideApp  
    .with(context)
    .asGif()
    .load(uri)
    .into(imageView);
```

This will solve your problem of showing gif bitmap in your application.

Comment: But i have this   Uri uri = data.getData(); and what is this gifBitmap?

Comment: I am unable to select gif images from the gallery while glide is used  to set this gif

Comment: edited my answer... you have to pass the ur that you have got while selection and glide will take care of it.... you can go and check the glide documentation attached with the answer as well.

Comment: Use Glide instead of GlideApp.. or check in their documentation.

Comment: it's not taking gif but take only image of it

Comment: getting exception    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference    in this-private String getImage(Bitmap bm) { int width = bm.getWidth(); } playerimagesave = getImage(bm);

Comment: your bitmap "bm" is null, so just check if your URI is correct and is returning correct bitmap value or not.

Comment: My image is setting from this but not gif